# How can I stop LightDM from crashing when unlocking if a DisplayPort monitor is disconnected?

Tags: lightdm

I've an Intel NUC6i3SYH running Debian GNU/Linux with LightDM 1.26.0-3, LightDM GTK+ Greeter 2.0.6-1 and Light Locker 1.8.0-3. When I lock my session, disconnect the DisplayPort cable from my monitor and the try to log in, LightDM crashes (but not really, since `systemctl status lightdm` still show shows the same time next to 'Active') and my session is lost. The following is the output of `journalctl` after trying to unlock (at 19:15 I pressed space to activate my greeter and at 19:16 I entered my login and pressed enter):

```
Feb 05 19:15:01 wb9688-nuc6i3syh CRON[4571]: pam_env(cron:session): Unable to open env file: /etc/environment: No such file or directory
Feb 05 19:15:01 wb9688-nuc6i3syh CRON[4571]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Feb 05 19:15:01 wb9688-nuc6i3syh CRON[4572]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Feb 05 19:15:01 wb9688-nuc6i3syh CRON[4571]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Feb 05 19:15:09 wb9688-nuc6i3syh kernel: [drm:intel_dp_start_link_train [i915]] *ERROR* failed to enable link training
Feb 05 19:15:11 wb9688-nuc6i3syh kernel: [drm:intel_dp_start_link_train [i915]] *ERROR* failed to enable link training
Feb 05 19:15:13 wb9688-nuc6i3syh kernel: [drm:intel_dp_start_link_train [i915]] *ERROR* failed to enable link training
Feb 05 19:16:06 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[1]: session-c4.scope: Killing process 4505 (lightdm) with signal SIGTERM.
Feb 05 19:16:06 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[1]: session-c4.scope: Killing process 4520 (lightdm-gtk-gre) with signal SIGTERM.
Feb 05 19:16:06 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[1]: Stopping Session c4 of user lightdm.
Feb 05 19:16:06 wb9688-nuc6i3syh lightdm[4505]: pam_unix(lightdm-greeter:session): session closed for user lightdm
Feb 05 19:16:06 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[1]: session-c4.scope: Succeeded.
Feb 05 19:16:06 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[1]: Stopped Session c4 of user lightdm.
Feb 05 19:16:07 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd-logind[594]: Removed session c4.
Feb 05 19:16:07 wb9688-nuc6i3syh pulseaudio[3889]: XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
Feb 05 19:16:07 wb9688-nuc6i3syh pulseaudio[3889]:       after 17 requests (17 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
Feb 05 19:16:07 wb9688-nuc6i3syh xfce4-notifyd[4491]: xfce4-notifyd: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
Feb 05 19:16:07 wb9688-nuc6i3syh at-spi-bus-launcher[3864]: XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
Feb 05 19:16:07 wb9688-nuc6i3syh at-spi-bus-launcher[3864]:       after 249 requests (249 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
Feb 05 19:16:07 wb9688-nuc6i3syh bluetoothd[597]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.405 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Feb 05 19:16:07 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[3770]: xfce4-notifyd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 05 19:16:07 wb9688-nuc6i3syh bluetoothd[597]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.405 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Feb 05 19:16:07 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[3770]: xfce4-notifyd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 05 19:16:07 wb9688-nuc6i3syh sudo[4480]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Feb 05 19:16:07 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[3770]: pulseaudio.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 05 19:16:07 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[3770]: pulseaudio.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 05 19:16:07 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[1]: session-5.scope: Killing process 3765 (lightdm) with signal SIGTERM.
Feb 05 19:16:07 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[1]: session-5.scope: Killing process 3835 (ssh-agent) with signal SIGTERM.
Feb 05 19:16:07 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[1]: session-5.scope: Killing process 3880 (agent) with signal SIGTERM.
Feb 05 19:16:07 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[1]: session-5.scope: Killing process 3892 (applet.py) with signal SIGTERM.
Feb 05 19:16:07 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[1]: Stopping Session 5 of user wb9688.
Feb 05 19:16:07 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[1]: session-5.scope: Succeeded.
Feb 05 19:16:07 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[1]: Stopped Session 5 of user wb9688.
Feb 05 19:16:07 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd-logind[594]: Removed session 5.
Feb 05 19:16:07 wb9688-nuc6i3syh acpid[600]: client 3724[0:0] has disconnected
Feb 05 19:16:07 wb9688-nuc6i3syh acpid[600]: client 4488[0:0] has disconnected
Feb 05 19:16:07 wb9688-nuc6i3syh acpid[600]: client connected from 4585[0:0]
Feb 05 19:16:07 wb9688-nuc6i3syh acpid[600]: 1 client rule loaded
Feb 05 19:16:07 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[3770]: pulseaudio.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.
Feb 05 19:16:07 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[3770]: pulseaudio.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
Feb 05 19:16:07 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[3770]: Stopped Sound Service.
Feb 05 19:16:07 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[3770]: Starting Sound Service...
Feb 05 19:16:07 wb9688-nuc6i3syh pulseaudio[4592]: W: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Stale PID file, overwriting.
Feb 05 19:16:08 wb9688-nuc6i3syh lightdm[4595]: pam_env(lightdm-greeter:session): Unable to open env file: /etc/environment: No such file or directory
Feb 05 19:16:08 wb9688-nuc6i3syh lightdm[4595]: pam_unix(lightdm-greeter:session): session opened for user lightdm by (uid=0)
Feb 05 19:16:08 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd-logind[594]: New session c5 of user lightdm.
Feb 05 19:16:08 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[1]: Started Session c5 of user lightdm.
Feb 05 19:16:09 wb9688-nuc6i3syh rtkit-daemon[609]: Supervising 0 threads of 0 processes of 1 users.
Feb 05 19:16:09 wb9688-nuc6i3syh rtkit-daemon[609]: Supervising 0 threads of 0 processes of 1 users.
Feb 05 19:16:09 wb9688-nuc6i3syh rtkit-daemon[609]: Supervising 0 threads of 0 processes of 1 users.
Feb 05 19:16:09 wb9688-nuc6i3syh rtkit-daemon[609]: Supervising 0 threads of 0 processes of 1 users.
Feb 05 19:16:09 wb9688-nuc6i3syh rtkit-daemon[609]: Supervising 0 threads of 0 processes of 1 users.
Feb 05 19:16:09 wb9688-nuc6i3syh rtkit-daemon[609]: Supervising 0 threads of 0 processes of 1 users.
Feb 05 19:16:09 wb9688-nuc6i3syh rtkit-daemon[609]: Supervising 0 threads of 0 processes of 1 users.
Feb 05 19:16:09 wb9688-nuc6i3syh rtkit-daemon[609]: Supervising 0 threads of 0 processes of 1 users.
Feb 05 19:16:09 wb9688-nuc6i3syh rtkit-daemon[609]: Supervising 0 threads of 0 processes of 1 users.
Feb 05 19:16:09 wb9688-nuc6i3syh rtkit-daemon[609]: Supervising 0 threads of 0 processes of 1 users.
Feb 05 19:16:09 wb9688-nuc6i3syh rtkit-daemon[609]: Supervising 0 threads of 0 processes of 1 users.
Feb 05 19:16:09 wb9688-nuc6i3syh rtkit-daemon[609]: Supervising 0 threads of 0 processes of 1 users.
Feb 05 19:16:09 wb9688-nuc6i3syh rtkit-daemon[609]: Supervising 0 threads of 0 processes of 1 users.
Feb 05 19:16:09 wb9688-nuc6i3syh rtkit-daemon[609]: Supervising 0 threads of 0 processes of 1 users.
Feb 05 19:16:09 wb9688-nuc6i3syh rtkit-daemon[609]: Supervising 0 threads of 0 processes of 1 users.
Feb 05 19:16:09 wb9688-nuc6i3syh rtkit-daemon[609]: Supervising 0 threads of 0 processes of 1 users.
Feb 05 19:16:09 wb9688-nuc6i3syh rtkit-daemon[609]: Supervising 0 threads of 0 processes of 1 users.
Feb 05 19:16:09 wb9688-nuc6i3syh rtkit-daemon[609]: Supervising 0 threads of 0 processes of 1 users.
Feb 05 19:16:09 wb9688-nuc6i3syh rtkit-daemon[609]: Supervising 0 threads of 0 processes of 1 users.
Feb 05 19:16:09 wb9688-nuc6i3syh rtkit-daemon[609]: Supervising 0 threads of 0 processes of 1 users.
Feb 05 19:16:09 wb9688-nuc6i3syh dbus-daemon[610]: [system] Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.650" (uid=1000 pid=4592 comm="/usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no ") interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager" member="GetManagedObjects" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.bluez" (uid=0 pid=597 comm="/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd ")
Feb 05 19:16:09 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[3770]: Started Sound Service.
Feb 05 19:16:09 wb9688-nuc6i3syh pulseaudio[4592]: E: [pulseaudio] bluez5-util.c: GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.650" (uid=1000 pid=4592 comm="/usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no ") interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager" member="GetManagedObjects" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.bluez" (uid=0 pid=597 comm="/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd ")
Feb 05 19:16:17 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 1000...
Feb 05 19:16:17 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[3770]: Stopped target Default.
Feb 05 19:16:17 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[3770]: Stopping Accessibility services bus...
Feb 05 19:16:17 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[3770]: Stopping D-Bus User Message Bus...
Feb 05 19:16:17 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[3770]: Stopping Virtual filesystem service...
Feb 05 19:16:17 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[3770]: Stopping Sound Service...
Feb 05 19:16:17 wb9688-nuc6i3syh at-spi-bus-launcher[3864]: Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key
Feb 05 19:16:17 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[3770]: gvfs-daemon.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=15/TERM
Feb 05 19:16:17 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[3770]: at-spi-dbus-bus.service: Succeeded.
Feb 05 19:16:17 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[3770]: Stopped Accessibility services bus.
Feb 05 19:16:17 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[3770]: run-user-1000-gvfs.mount: Succeeded.
Feb 05 19:16:17 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[3770]: dbus.service: Succeeded.
Feb 05 19:16:17 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[1]: run-user-1000-gvfs.mount: Succeeded.
Feb 05 19:16:17 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[3770]: Stopped D-Bus User Message Bus.
Feb 05 19:16:17 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[4509]: run-user-1000-gvfs.mount: Succeeded.
Feb 05 19:16:17 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[3770]: gvfs-daemon.service: Succeeded.
Feb 05 19:16:17 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[3770]: Stopped Virtual filesystem service.
Feb 05 19:16:17 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[3770]: pulseaudio.service: Succeeded.
Feb 05 19:16:17 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[3770]: Stopped Sound Service.
Feb 05 19:16:17 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[3770]: Stopped target Basic System.
Feb 05 19:16:17 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[3770]: Stopped target Paths.
Feb 05 19:16:17 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[3770]: Stopped target Timers.
Feb 05 19:16:17 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[3770]: Stopped target Sockets.
Feb 05 19:16:17 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[3770]: dirmngr.socket: Succeeded.
Feb 05 19:16:17 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[3770]: Closed GnuPG network certificate management daemon.
Feb 05 19:16:17 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[3770]: dbus.socket: Succeeded.
Feb 05 19:16:17 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[3770]: Closed D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
Feb 05 19:16:17 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[3770]: gpg-agent.socket: Succeeded.
Feb 05 19:16:17 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[3770]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache.
Feb 05 19:16:17 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[3770]: gpg-agent-browser.socket: Succeeded.
Feb 05 19:16:17 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[3770]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (access for web browsers).
Feb 05 19:16:17 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[3770]: gpg-agent-ssh.socket: Succeeded.
Feb 05 19:16:17 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[3770]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent (ssh-agent emulation).
Feb 05 19:16:17 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[3770]: gpg-agent-extra.socket: Succeeded.
Feb 05 19:16:17 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[3770]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (restricted).
Feb 05 19:16:17 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[3770]: pulseaudio.socket: Succeeded.
Feb 05 19:16:17 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[3770]: Closed Sound System.
Feb 05 19:16:17 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[3770]: Reached target Shutdown.
Feb 05 19:16:17 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[3770]: systemd-exit.service: Succeeded.
Feb 05 19:16:17 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[3770]: Started Exit the Session.
Feb 05 19:16:17 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[3771]: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session closed for user wb9688
Feb 05 19:16:17 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[3770]: Reached target Exit the Session.
Feb 05 19:16:17 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[1]: user@1000.service: Succeeded.
Feb 05 19:16:17 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 1000.
Feb 05 19:16:17 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[1]: Stopping User Runtime Directory /run/user/1000...
Feb 05 19:16:17 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[4509]: run-user-1000.mount: Succeeded.
Feb 05 19:16:17 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[1]: run-user-1000.mount: Succeeded.
Feb 05 19:16:17 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[1]: user-runtime-dir@1000.service: Succeeded.
Feb 05 19:16:17 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[1]: Stopped User Runtime Directory /run/user/1000.
Feb 05 19:16:17 wb9688-nuc6i3syh systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of UID 1000.
```

So, how can I stop LightDM from crashing when unlocking if a DisplayPort monitor is disconnected?

Comment: Do you disconnect the only monitor from the system and then connect it back?

Comment: @DenisNikolaenko: I have both a HDMI monitor and a DP monitor connected. The only one I disconnect is the DP monitor. I have the same issue on my laptop when I disconnect a VGA monitor (and of course keep the eDP monitor connected, since that's a bit hard to disconnect). I have no issue when I disconnect the HDMI monitor from my PC though.